# Поиск определенного значения на html странице

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что я не могу додуматься как можно узнать значение  , допустим - `m_bUseCustomAutoExposureMax` на странице `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frk1/hazedumper/master/csgo.cs`.
Мне нужно найти значение которое идет после `m_bUseCustomAutoExposureMax`, т.е - `0x9D9`.

Как можно использовать всю строку на которой находится `m_bUseCustomAutoExposureMax` с помощью `beautifulsoup4` или `re`?

(p.s: запрашиваю информацию с помощью `requests` так: `r = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frk1/hazedumper/master/csgo.cs")`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно: условие на поиск: после "имяпеременной" идут пробелы, затем =, затем пробелы, затем нужное значение, затем ;

В круглых скобках как раз нужный фрагмент.

```
text=requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frk1/hazedumper/master/csgo.cs")
match=re.search(r'm_bUseCustomAutoExposureMax\s+=\s+(.+);', text.text)
if match:
    print(match[1])
```

Comment: Не подскажите почему когда я запрашиваю с сайта нужное значение переменной и когда указываю в ручную - типы разные, хотя оба значение одинаково присвоены? Вот например: `match = re.search(r'dwGlowObjectManager\s+=\s+(.+);', r.text)` - `dwGlowObjectManager = (match[1])` - беру значение с сайта, и получаю STR тип, а если укажу переменную в ручную (`dwGlowObjectManager = (0x527CF70)`), то будет INT тип. Как можно это решить? (Нужно что бы запрос сайта был после INT типом, а не STR)

Comment: Это запись числа в шестнадцатеричной форме. Используйте int(match[1])